# Editing Channel Permission Overrides with Permission Value

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The [53-bit integer value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gsCV.png) defines the permissions of the bot. But one sentence confused me and it brought me to this easier idea.

> ...you can pass in keyword arguments denoting Permissions attributes ([quoted from here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.set_permissions))

I want to set my `VoiceChannel` permissions with the [`set_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.set_permissions) function, but using the 53-bit integer value (my idea is to set `value` in the [Permission](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) parameters), which would make everything much easier.

#### What I tried so far

- I tried setting the permission bit in the `overwrite` parameter of [set_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.set_permissions) with `discord.Permissions(value=..)`
- I tried not using `discord.Permissions`
- I tried setting in the `value` parameter of the `permissions` parameter for [set_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.set_permissions) as the integer (e.g. `value=1024`)

They all don't work. I didn't find anything about this so I guess it's either not possible or nobody thought about this.

#### The code I have so far

--- Just a example code cut out of my code ---

```py
ow_n = 1024

await voice_channel.set_permissions(everyone, permissions=ow_n)    # voice_channel & everyone defined corrrectly before
```

Error:

```
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: Invalid permissions given to keyword arguments
```

To reiterate my question, how do I set channel permission overrides using a permission bit integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

discord.py is a full fledged Discord API wrapper. There's no need to calculate the permission value yourself. discord.py has a helper class `PermissionOverwrite` for setting channel permissions (`Permissions` is different as it's used for server-wide role permissions).

The main difference between `Permissions` and `PermissionOverwrite`, is that `Permissions` has a fixed boolean value for each permission—either the permission is granted (True) or is not (False). Whereas `PermissionOverwrite` which is used for channel permissions overrides, has three possible values for each permission, the permission is explicitly granted (overrides role permission for this channel), the permission is explicitly denied  (overrides role permission for this channel), or this permission isn't overridden (unset, default role permission applies).

I believe you want to edit a voice channel and grant everyone the `VIEW_CHANNEL` permission (since that's the permission for 1024).

```
overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
overwrite.view_channel = True
await voice_channel.set_permissions(everyone, overwrite=overwrite)
```

Or as your quote is referring:

```
await voice_channel.set_permissions(everyone, view_channel=True)
```

---

Now to answer your question:

The reason why it's not possible to pass in a permission value directly to permission overrides is because it's too trivial to implement. For normal `Permissions`, it works because each flag bit that's set indicates that the permission is granted, while not set indicates that it's denied. This system wouldn't work for `PermissionOverwrite` since there's three states as mentioned earlier.

The only viable implementation would have `PermissionOverwrite` takes two permission bit values, one for "allowed" and one for "denied". This is actually how Discord API implement overrides. However, IMO this would cause confusion and wouldn't benefit much people.